# How to prevent the server caching css?

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, caching

How do I prevent the server caching css using .htaccess? I have tried the following

```
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# expire GIF images after a month in the client's cache
ExpiresByType style/css 1
```

Recommended by freenode users (#httpd).

However this made my server 500. 
What did they do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that made your server 500, but this is what my .htaccess files have looked like, and it's been working fine for me. Based off of [this .htaccess file](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) (section starting at line 668).

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ...

</IfModule>
```

You maybe will want to change this if/when the site goes into production.

Alternatively, I've gotten into the habit of versioning my css files, as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://path/style.css?v=0.03" />
```

Changing the 'version number' will force a reload. If you care to, you can automate this versioning process with PHP.